# Possible documentation error for the `defaultPackages` option

Tags: r

I believe I have found an incorrect statement in the documentation of the `defaultPackages` option. In R 4.2.0, it [reads](https://cran.r-project.org/manuals.html) (on pg. 438 of `fullrefman.pdf`)

```
     ‘defaultPackages’: the packages that are attached by default when
          R starts up.  Initially set from value of the environment
          variable ‘R_DEFAULT_PACKAGES’, or if that is unset to
          ‘c("datasets", "utils", "grDevices", "graphics", "stats",
          "methods")’.  (Set ‘R_DEFAULT_PACKAGES’ to ‘NULL’ or a
          comma-separated list of package names.)  It will not work to
          set this in a .Rprofile file, as its value is consulted
          before that file is read.
```

My question concerns the last sentence - actual behavior in R 3.4+ seems to contradict this. Here is a Dockerfile to demonstrate

```bash
# Dockerfile
FROM rocker/tidyverse

RUN echo "Example 1: Regular defaultPackages" | tee -a out.log
RUN R --quiet -e "search()" | tee -a out.log

RUN echo "Example 2: defaultPackages set to empty" | tee -a out.log
RUN echo "options(defaultPackages = c())" | tee ~/.Rprofile
RUN R --quiet -e "search()" | tee -a out.log

RUN echo "Example 3: defaultPackages appended with tidyverse" | tee -a out.log
RUN echo "options(defaultPackages = c(getOption('defaultPackages'), 'tidyverse'))" | tee ~/.Rprofile
RUN R --quiet -e "search()" | tee -a out.log

CMD cat out.log

# out.log
Example 1: Regular defaultPackages
> search()
[1] ".GlobalEnv"        "package:stats"     "package:graphics" 
[4] "package:grDevices" "package:utils"     "package:datasets" 
[7] "package:methods"   "Autoloads"         "package:base"     
> 
> 
Example 2: defaultPackages set to empty
> search()
[1] ".GlobalEnv"      "package:methods" "Autoloads"       "package:base"   
> 
> 
Example 3: defaultPackages appended with tidyverse
> search()
 [1] ".GlobalEnv"        "package:forcats"   "package:stringr"  
 [4] "package:dplyr"     "package:purrr"     "package:readr"    
 [7] "package:tidyr"     "package:tibble"    "package:ggplot2"  
[10] "package:tidyverse" "package:stats"     "package:graphics" 
[13] "package:grDevices" "package:utils"     "package:datasets" 
[16] "package:methods"   "Autoloads"         "package:base"
```

Am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an interpretation of the documentation that makes sense. Going to post this here for others that may be confused.

Consider the last sentence again

> It will not work to set this in a .Rprofile file, as its value is consulted before that file is read.

There are two valid interpretations: 1) the word "this" refers to `defaultPackages`, 2) the word "this" refers to `R_DEFAULT_PACKAGES`.

In the first interpretation, the statement is inaccurate, as supplied by the examples in my OP.

In the second interpretation, the statement is correct (though I must say, I don't think this is the natural interpretation of this sentence). Dockerfile to demonstrate.

```
# Dockerfile
FROM rocker/tidyverse:3.4

RUN echo "Example 4: R_DEFAULT_PACKAGES set to empty in .Rprofile" | tee -a out.log
RUN echo "Sys.setenv('R_DEFAULT_PACKAGES' = '')" | tee ~/.Rprofile
RUN R --quiet -e "search()" | tee -a out.log

RUN echo "Example 5: R_DEFAULT_PACKAGES set to tidyverse in .Rprofile" | tee -a out.log
RUN echo "Sys.setenv('R_DEFAULT_PACKAGES' = 'tidyverse')" | tee ~/.Rprofile
RUN R --quiet -e "search()" | tee -a out.log

CMD cat out.log

# out.log
Example 4: R_DEFAULT_PACKAGES set to empty in .Rprofile
> search()
[1] ".GlobalEnv"        "package:stats"     "package:graphics" 
[4] "package:grDevices" "package:utils"     "package:datasets" 
[7] "package:methods"   "Autoloads"         "package:base"     
> 
> 
Example 5: R_DEFAULT_PACKAGES set to tidyverse in .Rprofile
> search()
[1] ".GlobalEnv"        "package:stats"     "package:graphics" 
[4] "package:grDevices" "package:utils"     "package:datasets" 
[7] "package:methods"   "Autoloads"         "package:base"
```

Answer (score 0):

R 4.2.0, Ubuntu 22.04

```
edd@rob:~$ R --vanilla --quiet -e 'search()'
> search()
[1] ".GlobalEnv"        "package:stats"     "package:graphics" 
[4] "package:grDevices" "package:utils"     "package:datasets" 
[7] "package:methods"   "Autoloads"         "package:base"     
> 
> 
edd@rob:~$
```

I have `stats`.  Maybe something at your end is different?

Comment: Hmm, so when I use `search()` in R interactively I get only `[1] ".GlobalEnv"      "package:methods" "Autoloads"       "org:r-lib"      "package:base"`. But when I use your exact command, I get the same result as you. So it's something about the `--vanilla` flag or something about interactive R.

Comment: It may have to do with your default files in `RHOME/etc`.  Also `org:r-lib` seems unusual.  What OS do you use, and where did you get your version from?

Comment: Right, so the `--vanilla` flag ignores `.Rprofile`, so it makes sense that it shows `stats`. I'm confused that `?options` claims that I can't change `defaultPackages` in `.Rprofile`, because `defaultPackages` is consulted prior to `.Rprofile` loading, but I clearly can change it. Can you reproduce being able to change `defaultPackages` in `.Rprofile`?

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 and I downloaded R from the standard Rutter PPA.

Comment: I am also using your `r2u` PPA with `bspm`, if that makes any difference.

Comment: I use the same Ubuntu binaries (rebuilt from the Debian package I maintain) so it should really be the same.  I do not tweak the files in `/etc/R/*` (linked to/from `/usr/lib/R/etc` much -- and what I do later in my personal `~/.Rprofile` is skipped by `--vanilla`. Also, I just tried as `root`, same output.  "Something" must be different at your end, but I cannot tell what. Sorry!

Comment: Could you try setting your root's `.Rprofile` to `options(defaultPackages = c())` and then run `R --quiet -e 'search()'`? I'm pretty sure `stats` won't show up then.

Comment: It seems that `org:r-lib` shows up when R is used interactively, but not with `R -e`.

Comment: No I do not get `org:whatever` in interactive mode.  Same as above for me.

Comment: The difference between using the env.var and using `Rprofile` may be that I can avoid the (relatively expansive) package `methods` (which R used to not load  by default ...) in the former case of using `R_DEFAULT_PACKAGES=NULL`.

Comment: Well I'm stumped. Thank you for your time!

Comment: If your doubts remain after a back and forth with Dirk, who is an acknowledged R guru, You can post this on the R-dev mailing list where question of the accuracy of the documentation are often addressed.